# onSubmit binded does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind, onsubmit

I want to upload a file, my code worked on a old project, but on its, there is no way !

```
class JsonUploader extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {file: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);


}


handleChange(event){
    this.setState({file: event.target.files[0]});
}

handleSubmit(event){
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', this.state.file);
  data.append('name', this.state.file.filename);
  axios.post("/files", data).then((response) => {console.log(response.data)}).catch(console.log("Sending failed"));
}

render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(event) => {this.handleChange(event)}}/>
        <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    );
}
```

}

There is my class. As you can see, the handlers are binded. I don't know why nothing pass in first or second handler... I tried two ways (arrow and classic use) but same result..

My react app is a server side rendered app, i don't know if it change something..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: For one you should just need `onChange={this.handleChange}`. Two, you probably want `event.preventDefault()` in your `handleSubmit` function as it will attempt to send the form to the server when in reality you want an AJAX request.

Comment: I've put console.log at begining of handler and nothing pass in there, so event.preventDefault() is useless if my function is not accessed

Comment: Could you move this to a bin? I tried and everything seems to be working properly.

Comment: You can find original code here : https://github.com/Psyycker/react-express-router-webpack2 Juste add a simple form in any file and you'll see

Comment: You will need `event.preventDefault()` for this to work, also you can't guarantee that `console.log` will fire before the page reloads, it would be possible to miss it.

Comment: I just tried your example and it works as intended... also do include the `event.preventDefault()` as suggested, otherwise your `handleSubmit` won't work as expected...

Comment: So just put event.preventDefault() at beginning of my function ?

Comment: does not work for me. Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem and it could'nt work with the repo I gave.
In fact, I forgotten to add the  in my index.html with client.js ref.